# Trackers in colab

Tags: opencv, google-colaboratory

I wonder if it is possible to use opencv trackers (Tracker api) on google colab. Till now I was not able to use this feature on google colab.

P.S.1 I was able to use this feature  offline on my laptop. but the problem is my gpu has cuda version 2.1 . sad

P.S.2 The notebook I used can be found at

https://github.com/vahidajalluian/YOLO-V3-Keras-from-scratch/blob/master/Tracking_Notebook.ipynb

Rest of files  needed to load this notebook can be found at this repo
https://github.com/vahidajalluian/YOLO-V3-Keras-from-scratch

Comment: What did you try, and what problem did you encounter? Can you share a notebook that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @BobSmith I'v added the notebook address in question